# IntelliJ - Change textsize of Project menu only

Tags: intellij-idea

I have my Project menu in View Mode = Window.

Is there a way to only change the textsize in this menu, and nothing else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it bigger, try adding `-Dbigger.font.in.project.view=true` to VM arguments - or make sure that it's not set to false - via **Help | Edit Custom VM Options**.

A YouTrack request exists to make it a full-fledged feature: [IDEA-209037](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-209037). You are welcome to vote for it.